# Google Chrome v63+ print to pdf css not working

Tags: css, google-chrome

Does anyone know why print to pdf does not apply all the css properly in newer versions of google chrome? This started happening from v64. Try to do print-preview for [sample page](http://www.feetplc.co.uk/fund-factsheet).  For time-being I have fixed this issue by adding separate css for @print.

I was just wondering if someone knows the reason why google has decided to do this? or is it a bug?